# Alternative to `MainTemplate.hooks.beforeStartup` in Webpack@5

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to migrate a plugin from webpack 4 -> 5, however it's using `MainTemplate.hooks.beforeStartup` and webpack throws

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: MainTemplate.hooks.beforeStartup has been removed (use RuntimeGlobals.startup instead)
```

yet I haven't found any information on how to use `RuntimeGlobals.startup`, so what's the proper alternative this hook and how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after some time, seems like [someone](https://github.com/Kooneko/livereload-webpack-plugin/) finally has figured it out.

So according to [him](https://github.com/Kooneko)

```js
if (isWebpack4) {
            compilation.mainTemplate.hooks.startup.tap(this.pluginName, (source) => {
                return (this.options.appendScript && this.isRunning())
                    ? require('./autoloadScript')(this.options) + source
                    : source;
            });
        } else {
            compilation.hooks.additionalChunkRuntimeRequirements.tap(this.pluginName, (chunk, set) => {
                set.add(RuntimeGlobals.require);
                set.add(RuntimeGlobals.startup);

                const LiveReloadRuntimeModule = require('./LiveReloadRuntimeModule');
                compilation.addRuntimeModule(chunk, new LiveReloadRuntimeModule(this.options));
            })
        }
```

The alternative seems to be `compilation.hooks.additionalChunkRuntimeRequirements`. I haven't tested myself though